# Errors does not show/ Rails, simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I want to show errors when they are in form and can not understand why this code does not work.
**hotel.rb**

```
class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base
...
  has_many :comments
...
end
```

**comment.rb**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :hotel
  belongs_to :user
  delegate :email, to: :user, prefix: true

  validates :body, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5, maximum:200 }
end
```

**hotels/show.**

```
...
    %h2 Comments
    #comments
      .ui.piled.blue.segment
        .ui.header
          %i.icon.inverted.circular.blue.comment
          Comments
        .ui.comments
          = render :partial => @hotel.comments
        = render 'comments/form', comment: @hotel.comments
...
```

**_form**

```
-if user_signed_in?
  = simple_form_for [@hotel, Comment.new] do |f|
    =f.error_notification
    %br
    .ui.reply.form
      .field
        =f.label :body, "New comment"
        =f.input :body, as: :text, label: false
        =f.submit 'Add comment', class: "ui fluid blue labeled submit icon button"
-else
  =link_to 'Sign in to add comment', new_user_session_path, class: 'ui blue button'
```

**_comment**

```
= div_for comment do
  .comment
    .content
      %span.author= comment.user_email
      .metadata
        %span.date Posted #{time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at)} ago
    .text
      = comment.body
```

If you add too_short and too_long model that does not correct the.

**UPDATE**

**comments_controller**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:hotel_id])
    @comment = @hotel.comments.new(comment_params)
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id
    @comment.save
    redirect_to @hotel
end

private
  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:user_id, :body, :hotel_id)
  end
end
```

Comment: whats in your controllers? could you post it too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is in your controller.  Error's won't populate until you try and save the record.  Well in your instance you don't have any flow control to see if it saved, you just have `@comment.save`.  If it doesn't save or if it does save, you do the same redirect.

Try this:

```
  if @comment.save
    redirect_to @hotel, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.'
  else
    redirect_to @hotel, notice: 'There was an issue trying to save your comment.'
  end
```

Now with `render :new`, `@comment.errors` will be populated (assuming you tried an invalid length) and now you should see the error messages displayed!

Comment: I do not have a new template fo comments, if I use `redirect_to @hotel` comment.errors will work? For creating comment I use partial (_form)

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem.

**comments_controller**

```
 def create
    @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:hotel_id])
    @comment = @hotel.comments.new(comment_params)
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id
    @comment.save
    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @hotel }
      else
        format.html { render partial: 'comments/form' }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**_form**

```
-if user_signed_in?
  = simple_form_for [@hotel, @comment] do |f|
    - if @comment.errors.any?
      #error_explanation
        %h2
          = pluralize(@comment.errors.count, "error")
          prohibited this comment from being saved:
        %ul
          - @comment.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
            %li= msg
    %br
    .ui.reply.form
      =f.error_notification
      .inputs
        =f.label :body, "New comment"
        =f.input :body, as: :text, label: false
      .actions
        =f.button :submit, 'Add comment', class: "ui fluid blue labeled submit icon button"
-else
  =link_to 'Sign in to add comment', new_user_session_path, class: 'ui blue button'
%br
```

This code render comment form when the comment doesn't save, and write the errors.

Comment: That's exactly what I said - please accept my answer.